# How can I know the spoken language of the assistant?

Tags: actions-on-google

I want to know in my fulfillment what was the language the user was spoken when the intent was triggered.

Is there a way to know that? I didn't find that information in the request header or in the request data.

Thanks

Guzman

Answer (score 0):

This information is part of the user locale and is part of the JSON body that is sent. You can get this in one of a few ways:

- If you're using the node.js library, you can use `app.getUserLocale()`
- If you're using the Action SDK, this is in the JSON at `user.locale`
- If you're using Dialogflow, this is in the JSON at `originalRequest.data.user.locale`

In each case, the value returned will be something like `en-US` specifying the language and locale the user is using.

Keep in mind that you will still need to register your Action to handle these languages or language/locale pairs in the Action console.

Comment: Hi, I'm using actions sdk but the json body I'm receiving looks like this:{
    "inputs": [
        {
            "intent": "action.devices.SYNC"
        }
    ],
    "requestId": "5250293014031690856"
}.  There is no user field, neither in the headers.

Comment: Actually, what I'm doing is building a Smart Home app, so doing as it is described here: https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/action-packages is not possible